# UITableView scrollToRow breaks UIView.animate() in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I want to create a chat-like view, and in order to simulate a message being written, I have added a dot-bubble cell, with the dot's alphas animating from 0 to 1.

I have added this animation in the custom cell's `layoutSubviews()` method.

[image]

However, I am also calling `tableView.scrollToRow()` so the table view always shows the last cells to the user. But I realized that calling this method would break the animations inside of my cells (whether I am animating or not the `scrollToRow()` method).

What should I do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create two instance method in Your typing indicator cell
one for start animation and another for resetAnimation

```
class TypingCell: UITableViewCell {
    fileprivate let MIN_ALPHA:CGFloat = 0.35

    @IBOutlet weak var dot0: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dot1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dot2: UIView!

    private func startAnimation() {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .calculationModeLinear], animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.1666, animations: {
            self.dot0.alpha = MIN_ALPHA
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.16, relativeDuration: 0.1666, animations: {
            self.dot0.alpha = 1
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.33, relativeDuration: 0.1666, animations: {
            self.dot1.alpha = MIN_ALPHA
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.49, relativeDuration: 0.1666, animations: {
            self.dot1.alpha = 1
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.66, relativeDuration: 0.1666, animations: {
            self.dot2.alpha = MIN_ALPHA
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.83, relativeDuration: 0.1666, animations: {
            self.dot2.alpha = 1
            })
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func resetAnimation() {
        dot0.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        dot1.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        dot2.layer.removeAllAnimations()

        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.startAnimation() }
    }

}
```

Reset your animation on `tableView(_: willDisplay: cell: forRowAt:)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = cell as? TypingCell {
        cell.resetAnimation()
    }
}
```

Comment: `willDisplay cell:` was definitely the trick! Thanks a lot ;)